# what is parent transaction in ethereum

Tags: transactions, ether, etherscan

I am learning about ethereum, when I learn I came across a term

> Parent transaction Hash

I would like to know regarding this

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: I read it in #etherscan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: My answer was incorrect, please see Sileo's answer. (Unable to delete this because this is an accepted answer)

Comment: In this answer, I think you're confusing the parent block hash (or parent hash) with the parent tx hash of an internal tx (call or deployment), see my answer below.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the heads-up! Will edit

Comment: In fact, I'll just delete, since your answer is accurate.. except I can't delete this, so I'll just edit

Answer (score 2):

Answering here because I found this question through a search engine.

While inspecting a block, I've come accross the phrase `Parent Tx Hash`. It shows up when looking at the internal transactions that happened inside a specific block. (https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?block=14744326) This is because the internal transactions are executed by a contract but always initiated from an EOA. The parent transaction hash is therefore the hash of the transaction in which the internal call happened.

A contract can for example send ETH to 3 addresses, which would result in 3 internal transactions showing up, but having the same origin, the same parent transaction hash.